# A PhD in Informatics vs CS?

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions, career-path

I just had a conversation with an adviser who mentioned that there is little value in a PhD in informatics (specifically biomedical), when compared to a pure CS PhD. I have a background in computer science now, and am looking to stay in this field. However, my adviser makes the argument that to truly bring about innovation in this field (or really any interdisciplinary one) one needs to be grounded well in the basics of one of the pertaining fields. What is the truth to this, and would I be able to get this with a PhD in informatics?

EDIT: Sorry, forgot to include the location. I'm from the United States.

Comment: Where are you from?  I have a friend studying "doctorat en informatique" in Europe, but there "informatique" is the literal translation of "computer science" into French, which means they are the same. Just saying...

Comment: USA, sorry about the confusion

Comment: What should be included to make this post more specific?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on where you are and more on the details of the degree. Many other places than France use some variation on Information *, rather than Computer Science. Denmark for one. Others as well. In the US an information science or informatics degree is more often closer to a management degree than a CS degree.

However, details matter. Algorithms, Languages and Compilers, AI, and such will make it a CS degree whatever its name.

However, if it lacks those but has courses such as Information Processing or Transaction Processing or Decision Support Systems it may be not CS but something related.

Such courses as Database Management Systems could be in either, though a CS degree will focus more on the theory of databases and such things as Entity Relationship modeling.

In the US at least it is a bit confusing. But the general idea is that a CS degree is more focused on theory and an IS (Information Systems) degree is more (but not completely) focused on practice.

Careers can be built with either degree.

However, I'm surprised that anyone would think biomedical information systems is somehow a lesser art. There are many very serious issues that still need to be resolved in such systems and such study should cover such "hard" topics as security and encryption. But, details matter.

On the other hand, your advisor is correct in that to make progress in an interdisciplinary field you should start with a firm grounding in one or the other. There will still be a lot to learn, but the grounding in one will help you focus on what you need from the other.

Comment: Thank you for the response! In a related note, a lot of my discussions seem to have centered around coursework. How important is that when making this decision, considering the most of the PhD is focused on research.

Comment: @vsocrates, the course list will also give you some idea of what the professors are interested in and what sorts of research they do. It is just an easy way to determine that without needing to examine a lot of professor's publications.